# Why does the time matter in web services?

Tags: web-services

In WCF web services (or all web services?), if the client and server times are off you get a security exception.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

It is a pain if you are building client server services and the time has to be accurate?

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx

Comment: Is there a default security implementation being used? I know that Windows (2000 and later) use an implementation of Kerberos for most network security, and Kerberos systems use time synchronization to prevent replay attacks (as Darron and Arjan both mention).

Comment: Why is it a pain for the time to be accurate?  The OS keeps it synchronized for you automatically using NTP on any operating system made in the last 10 years...

Comment: rmeader: if you have clients who can barely restart their computer it is a pain.  And from what I heard some versions of windows don't automatically synch time ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that this is to make replay attacks harder.  These are attacks where a legitimate request and/or response captured by an attacker is sent again at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that too.

My guess is that it is a securitymeassure. It will make it more difficult to record and replay messages, and sending them to the service repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) on both server and client to have their clocks synchronized, and you should be OK (unless I am missing something specific). NTP has servers worldwide and can work on both Unix and Windows. In Windows it is even a system property since at least WinXP times: check Date/Time settings "Internet Time" tab, and enter any of the publicly available NTP servers closest to you.